# Is it possible to connect via ssl to a remote mysql db using php without certificates or keys?

Tags: php, mysql, database, ssl, pdo

Lets say I have a client that gives me db credentials, and they want to connect to the db with a secure/encrypted. They also enabled ssl in their mysql setup. When they give me their db creds, i dont want to ask them for keys and certs. So is it possible to have a encrypted secure connection via ssl when connecting to the clients db with out those items?

**update:**
so after further tinkering around

```
$db->ssl_set(NULL, NULL,'/path_to_self_signed_cert/ca.pem',NULL,'');
$db->real_connect('hostname','username','password','dbname', 
'port'socket', MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT);`
```

doing this got me the outcome i wanted after running this

```
$db->query("SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';");
```

displayed the cipher algorithm instead of being blank

```
  (
   [0] => Ssl_cipher
   [Variable_name] => Ssl_cipher
   [1] => DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
   [Value] => DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
  )
```

but dont really know why this worked, is a self signed cert the proper way of doing this ?

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit? If the db has been setup correctly already, the SSL certs should be valid and establishing a secure connection should be as simple as using the db credentials they provided you with. They shouldn't have to give you any additional keys or certs.

Comment: @rickjerrity I was thinking you needed some kind certificates or keys to establish a secure encrypted connection between client and server. Is there php code to verify that the connection is encrypted for sanity sake ?

Comment: I have posted an answer to your question. Feel free to edit your original question or comment here/the answer if you need further clarification on things.

Comment: You don't need keys, but you do need php to be compiled with OpenSSL so php can make the handshake.

Comment: It is technically possible to establish a TLS handshake without using X.509 certificates but what kind of security do you think you get then? Almost nothing because, contrary to intuition, authentication matters more than confidentiality and authentication is featured by the use of X.509 certificates. In your case, as a client you definitively want to check server certificate (hence you need its certificate and/or its CA certificate) and the server may with to authenticate you through a certificate that you can create yourself locally.

Comment: @rickjerrity the client has to check the server certificate if it wishes to have a decent level of security which most often means taking great care on which CA you put your trust. See this paper: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf

Comment: @rickjerrity i left a reply to your answer below

Answer (score 1):

@rickjerrity i connect to my remote db via command line, and check the status by running `\s` and says `SSL: Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA`. But when i connect to the same database using php and using the same credentials it says the cipher is empty. here is the code I used to connect to the remote db

```
$db = mysqli_init();
    $db->real_connect('hostname','username','password','dbname');
    $res = $db->query("SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';");
    while ( $row = $res->fetch_array() ) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $db->close();
```

and the response is

```
[0] => Ssl_cipher
[Variable_name] => Ssl_cipher
[1] => 
[Value] =>
```

Answer (score 0):

No client side certificate or key should be needed for a secure db connection, besides the db credentials. PHP should verify SSL cert integrity upon connection. Any other PHP methods capable of verifying the connection's encryption status would be for sanity sake, like you mentioned. If you show some specific code examples we may be able to assist further.

Comment: As mentioned by Anthony in a comment above, this might be a PHP configuration issue. According to Anthony, PHP must have been compiled with OpenSSL in order for it to actually establish a TLS connection. Double check that you are able to establish any TLS connections with any valid websites using PHP.